# Using javascript, how do I stop Images from reloading?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I have 2 buttons. Each button show a different array. Everything works good except, say I want to go back to the first it reloads the images. So the first time I click the button, my 6 images show up. The second time a todal of 12. and so on. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Can't seem to find anything online.

```
var picArray1 = new Array("concert1","concert2","concert3","concert4","concert5","concert6");
var picArray2 = new Array("out1","out2","out3","out4","out5","out6");


function showArray1() {
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("gallery")
        for(i=0; i<picArray1.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+picArray1[i]+'.jpg">';
            document.getElementById("text2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("text1").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

function showArray2() {
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById("gallery")
        for(i=0; i<picArray2.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+picArray2[i]+'.jpg">';
            document.getElementById("text1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("text2").style.display = 'block';

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let's do some factorisation :

```
function show(list,galleryId,text1Id,text2Id) {
        var imgDiv = document.getElementById(galleryId)
        var text1 = document.getElementById(text1Id);
        var text2 = document.getElementById(text2Id);
        text2.innerHTML = "" // important part
        for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            text2.innerHTML += '<img src="images/'+list[i]+'.jpg">';
            text1.style.display = 'none';
            text2.style.display = 'block';

        }
    }
// call the function
show(['image1','image2','image3'],"gallery","text1","text2")
// not sure why you are getting imgDiv though since you are not using it.
```